# Get Percentage Of Difference Between 2 Numbers

Tags: c++, math

I have an issue with this, for some reason.

I have 2 large numbers (`unsigned long long`), and I need to calculate the percentage difference between the 2.

For example, if the first one is `11` and the second one is `1313`, the result should be a `+196%` difference.

I have tried multiple calculations, but none work properly.

**1)** `Diff = 100 x ((|A - B|) / ((A + B) / 2))`

I am not at all good at math, but I looked it up and found the `|` is absolute of `A-B`. So I tried using the `abs()` function from `math.h`, but it did not explicitly take my `unsigned long long` so I assumed better not cast it and mess the number up and figured maybe I can just pass the raw values. This is the function (as lambda):

```
auto percentageChange = [](unsigned long long Old, unsigned long long New)
                -> double
            {
                double fPer{};

                if ((0ul != Old) && (0ul != New))
                {
                    fPer = static_cast<double>(100ul * ((New - Old) / ((New + Old) / 2ul)));
                }

                return fPer;
            };
```

Some sample results:

```
Old = 225194918
New = 225202494
Difference = 0.0%

Old = 0
New = 1421
Difference = 0.0%

Old = 0
New = 6015
Difference = 0.0%

Old = 19874312
New = 20871647015
Difference = 100.0%

Old = 847
New = 876
Difference = 0.0%
```

How they are printed:

```
        printf("Old = %llu\nNew = %llu\nDifference = %.1f%%\n\n", Old, New, fPer);
```

**2)** I found the following on the `geeksforgeeks.org` website:

```
B = New
A = Old

Diff = ((B - A) * 100) / A
```

Here is the code:

```
    auto percentageChange = [](unsigned long long Old, unsigned long long New)
        -> double
    {
        double fPer{};

        if ((0ul != Old) && (0ul != New))
        {
            fPer = static_cast<double>(((New - Old) * 100) / Old);
        }

        return fPer;
    };
```

Here are some sample results from it (all unsigned long long, of course):

```
Old = 225080173
New = 225087090
Difference = 0.0%

Old = 0
New = 968
Difference = 0.0%

Old = 15
New = 5921
Difference = 39373.0%

Old = 22448658
New = 19328478723
Difference = 86000.0%

Old = 847
New = 876
Difference = 3.0%
```

How they are printed:

```
        printf("Old = %llu\nNew = %llu\nDifference = %.1f%%\n\n", Old, New, fPer);
```

**So, where am I messing up? Am I overflowing the integers somehow? Am I printing them wrong? Did I mess up the calculations? I cannot see the error myself. Thanks!**

Answer (score 0):

On this line:

```
fPer = static_cast<double>(100ul * ((New - Old) / ((New + Old) / 2ul)));
```

you are doing integer division, and *then* casting the result to a double. Note that a calculation like `1/2` is equal to `0`, *not* `0.5`.

Instead, cast the innermost value to a double, and then all the other computations will follow as floating-point calculations, like this:

```
fPer = 100ul * ((New - Old) / (static_cast<double>(New + Old) / 2ul));
                               // innermost value ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: The results are still not good, sadly. The difference between `0` and `1171` is `0.0%` according to the program now.

Comment: What do you *want* the percentage difference to be when the starting value is `0`? An answer of `0` seems reasonable, all though infinity might be better.

Comment: I don't know why that wouldn't make sense as, like I said, I don't understand math, but I would need a result like 200%. I assume that if it is `0`, I can just switch it to a `1` and get the a close number to what I need

Comment: You want the percentage difference between `0` and `1171` to be `200%`? I'm sorry, I don't understand that math at all. For what it's worth, I would recommend clearing up the math for yourself *before* writing any code. Code is the easy part, but you *have* to be clear on what it is your program is supposed to do *exactly*.

Comment: I see now what you mean after thinking about it, but in my program I sometimes start from the value 0 and then it increases to something like 1000 and I need to know by how much it increased expressed as a percentage for better readability.

Comment: Ok, then assume it started from `1` and then the percentage difference is just the new number. e.g. `0` to `1000` would be a `1000%` percent increase (though not really of course).

Comment: @cigien Casting a 64-bit `unsigned long long` to a 64-bit `double` will cause a loss of precision because `double` only has 52 bits of precision vs. 64 bits in the `unsigned long long`.

Comment: It isn't meaningful to say how much a value has increased from "nothing" in percentages. Usually in these cases you'd first leave the growth rate empty or write "n/a" or something like that and start showing the percentages only after it makes sense.

Comment: Both implementations return zero when one of the inputs is zero. So for the inputs `0` and `1171`, the expected answer actually is `0.0%`. Not saying that's correct, but obviously this is an exercise and it's handles the first number being zero in this way rather than terminating or returning infinity.

Answer (score 0):

The two equations you provided are different, so you're going to get two different answers even if you implement both of them correctly.

Usually when someone says "percent difference" they want to know, how large is the difference between these two values, as a percentage of the first value?

- (B - A) is the difference
- To determine "as a percentage of the first value" we solve the proportion: (B - A) / A = x / 100

  - Ax = (B - A) * 100
  - x = ((B - A) * 100) / A

That's the equation you got from `geeksforgeeks.org`.

If A = 5 and B = 20, then the answer is 300, in other words, B is 300% greater than A; 300% of A is 15, and added to A gives 20.

I'm not sure what the other equation is calculating. You're taking the absolute difference between the two values, dividing by the average, then multiplying by 100.

If again A = 5 and B = 20, then the absolute difference is 15, and dividing by the average of 12.5 gives 1.2, times 100 gives 120%. I don't see how that's descriptive of the relationship between B and A.

Back to the `geeksforgeeks.org` equation. A problem occurs when A is greater than B, because now the result is negative, but you're using `unsigned long long` values, so you can't represent negative numbers. If it's necessary for you to handle this case, you'll have to check for `A > B` first, then do the math in terms of (A - B) and then negate the sign of the result.

For example, if A = 20 and B = 5, then we can't do (B - A), so we do (A - B) giving 15, times 100 is 1500, divided by A is 75, then negate that, -75. In other words, B is 75% less than A.